# Access resources by Id in Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I just started playing with Azure DocumentDB and my excitement has turned into confusion. This thing is weird. It seems like everything (databases, collections, documents) needs to be accessed not by its id, but by its 'SelfLink'. For example:

I create a database:

```
public void CreateDatabase()
{
    using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authKey))
    {
        Database db = new Database()
        {
            Id = "TestDB",
        };
        client.CreateDatabaseAsync(db).Wait();
    }
}
```

Then later sometime I want to create a Collection:

```
public void CreateCollection()
{
    using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authKey))
    {
        DocumentCollection collection = new DocumentCollection()
        {
            Id = "TestCollection",
        };
        client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(databaseLink: "???", documentCollection: collection).Wait();
    }
}
```

The api wants a 'databaseLink' when what I'd really prefer to give it is my database Id. I don't have the 'databaseLink' handy. Does DocumentDB really expect me to pull down a list of all databases and go searching through it for the databaseLink everytime I want to do anything?

This problem goes all the way down. I can't save a document to a collection without having the collection's 'link'.

```
public void CreateDocument()
{
    using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authKey))
    {
        client.CreateDocumentAsync(documentCollectionLink: "???", document: new { Name = "TestName" }).Wait();
    }
}
```

So to save a document I need the collection's link. To get the collections link I need the database link. To get the database link I have to pull down a list of all databases in my account and go sifting through it. Then I have to use that database link that I found to pull down a list of collections in that database that I then have to sift through looking for the link of the collection I want. This doesn't seem right.

Am I missing something? Am I not understanding how to use this? Why am I assigning ids to all my resources when DocumentDB insists on using its own link scheme to identify everything? My question is 'how do I access DocumentDB resources by their Id?'

Comment: if you would like to see the feature implemented, please go vote for it on http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb that would help us prioritize asks from users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend you look at the code samples [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Azure-DocumentDB-NET-Code-6b3da8af) in particular the DocumentDB.Samples.ServerSideScripts project.

In the Program.cs you will find the `GetOrCreateDatabaseAsync` method:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Get or create a Database by id
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="id">The id of the Database to search for, or create.</param> 
/// <returns>The matched, or created, Database object</returns> 
private static async Task<Database> GetOrCreateDatabaseAsync(string id) 
{ 
    Database database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery()
        .Where(db => db.Id == id).ToArray().FirstOrDefault(); 
    if (database == null) 
    { 
        database = await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(
            new Database { Id = id }); 
    } 

    return database; 
}
```

To answer you question, you can use this method to find your database by its id and other resources (collections, documents etc.) using their respective Create[ResourceType]Query() methods.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This, apparently, is the best way to do this with DocumentDB at the moment.

Comment: The CreateDatabaseQuery method no longer exists on the client object. Trying to find a replacement....

Comment: Looks like it's an extension method. Need to include the following in the using section "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq"

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.linq.documentservicequeryable.createdatabasequery.aspx

Comment: I've found this to be a good, more recent setup of documentDB examples.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/blob/ea5df70635751f6dc8f4eeb7587f820a61ce9c67/samples/DocumentDB.Samples.CollectionManagement/app.js

Answer (score 9):

*The information posted in other answers from 2014 is now somewhat out of date. Direct addressing by Id is possible:*

Although **_selflinks** still exist, and can be used to access resources, Microsoft have since added a much simpler way to locate resources by their Ids that does not require you to retain the **_selflink** :

> UriFactory
>
> UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId))
>
> UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, "document id");

This enables you to create a safe Uri (allowing for example for whitespace) - which is functionally identical to the resources **_selflink**; the example given in the Microsoft announcement is shown below:

```
// Use **UriFactory** to build the DocumentLink
Uri docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("SalesDb", "Catalog", "prd123");

// Use this constructed Uri to delete the document
await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(docUri);
```

The announcement, from **August 13th 2015**, can be found here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-documentdb-bids-fond-farewell-to-self-links/

Answer (score 1):

The create database call returns a the database object:

```
var database = client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = databaseName }).Result.Resource;
```

And then you can use that to create your collection

```
var spec = new DocumentCollection { Id = collectionName };
spec.IndexingPolicy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.Consistent;
spec.IndexingPolicy.Automatic = true;
spec.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(new IndexingPath { IndexType = IndexType.Range, NumericPrecision = 6, Path = "/" });
var options = new RequestOptions
{
    ConsistencyLevel = ConsistencyLevel.Session
};

var collection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(database.SelfLink, spec, options).Result.Resource;
```

Answer (score 1):

The client.Create... methods return the objects which have the self links you are looking for

```
Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(
    new Database { Id = "Foo"});
DocumentCollection collection = await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
    database.SelfLink, new DocumentCollection { Id = "Bar" });
Document document = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(
    collection.SelfLink, new { property1 = "Hello World" });
```

Answer (score -1):

For deleting the document in partitioned collection, please leverage this format:

```
result = await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(selfLink, new RequestOptions {
    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey)
});
```